# Tengo un problema con el metodo getParameter en un select de html

Tags: netbeans

estoy realizando un javaweb en netbeans para calcular el area de tres figura el circulo el triangulo y el rectagulo, el problema es que cuando ejecuto el programa me sale el error 500 y me dice que figur es igual a null, nose que esta mal o como se utiliza muy bien el metodo, agradeceria mucho la ayuda aqui esta el codigo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Area de Figuras</title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       function showForm() {
           var figura = document.getElementById("figuras").value;
           if (figura == "circulo") {
               document.getElementById("form_circulo").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("form_triangulo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("form_rectangulo").style.display = "none";
           } else if (figura == "triangulo") {
               document.getElementById("form_circulo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("form_triangulo").style.display = "block";
               document.getElementById("form_rectangulo").style.display = "none";
           } else if (figura == "rectangulo") {
               document.getElementById("form_circulo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("form_triangulo").style.display = "none";
               document.getElementById("form_rectangulo").style.display = "block";
           }
       }
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Area de Figuras</h1>
   <select id="figuras" onchange="showForm()" >
       <option value="">Seleccione una figura</option>
       <option value="circulo" name="figuras">Circulo</option>
       <option value="triangulo" name="figuras">Triangulo</option>
       <option value="rectangulo" name="figuras">Rectangulo</option>
   </select>
   <form id="form_circulo" style="display: none;" action="AreaServlet" method="post">
       <h2>Circulo</h2>
       <label for="radio">Radio:</label>
       <input type="number" id="radio" name="radio">
       <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
   </form>
   <form id="form_triangulo" style="display: none;" action="AreaServlet" method="post">
       <h2>Triangulo</h2>
       <label for="base">Base:</label>
       <input type="number" id="base" name="base">
       <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
       <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura">
       <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
   </form>
   <form id="form_rectangulo" style="display: none;" action="AreaServlet" method="post">
       <h2>Rectangulo</h2>
       <label for="base">Base:</label>
       <input type="number" id="base" name="base">
       <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
       <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura">
       <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Y aqui esta el servlet, el error me dice que el problema esta en el renglon 16 ya que no puedo comparar algo que esta vacio,

```
import java.io.IOException;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/AreaServlet")
public class AreaServlet extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
       String figur = request.getParameter("figuras");
       double resultado = 0;

       if (figur.equals("circulo")) {
           double radio = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("radio"));
           resultado = Math.PI * radio * radio;
       } else if (figur.equals("triangulo")) {
           double base = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("base"));
           double altura = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("altura"));
           resultado = 0.5 * base * altura;
       } else if (figur.equals("rectangulo")) {
           double base = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("base"));
           double altura = Double.parseDouble(request.getParameter("altura"));
           resultado = base * altura;
       }

       request.setAttribute("area", resultado);
       request.getRequestDispatcher("area.jsp").forward(request, response);
   }
}
```

LLevo bastante tiempo lidiando con este problema y aun no logro identificar cual es el fallo.

Answer (score 1):

Evidentemente esto `request.getParameter("figuras");` te está retornando `null`, porque el `select` cuyo `name` es `figuras` está fuera del form y lo que está fuera del form no se envía

Lo mejor en tu caso es usar un solo `form` y dividirlos en `fieldset` el cual tiene un atributo `disabled`, cuando el fieldset es disabled no envía nada de lo de dentro

```js
function showForm() {
   var figura = document.getElementById("figuras").value;
   document.querySelectorAll("fieldset").forEach(a=>a.disabled=true);
   document.getElementById("form_" + figura).disabled=false;
}
```

```css
fieldset[disabled]{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<form action="AreaServlet" method="post">
 <h1>Area de Figuras</h1>
 <select id="figuras" onchange="showForm()" >
     <option value="">Seleccione una figura</option>
     <option value="circulo" name="figuras">Circulo</option>
     <option value="triangulo" name="figuras">Triangulo</option>
     <option value="rectangulo" name="figuras">Rectangulo</option>
 </select>
 <fieldset id="form_circulo" disabled>
     <h2>Circulo</h2>
     <label for="radio">Radio:</label>
     <input type="number" id="radio" name="radio">
     <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
 </fieldset>
 
  <fieldset id="form_triangulo" disabled>
     <h2>Triangulo</h2>
     <label for="base">Base:</label>
     <input type="number" id="base" name="base">
     <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
     <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura">
     <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset id="form_rectangulo" disabled>
     <h2>Rectangulo</h2>
     <label for="base">Base:</label>
     <input type="number" id="base" name="base">
     <label for="altura">Altura:</label>
     <input type="number" id="altura" name="altura">
     <input type="submit" value="Calcular Area">
 </fieldset>
```